# maven : test fails when calling from intellij

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, intellij-idea

This call, initiatied from within intellij's maven window, results in a failed test :

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin\java" -Dmaven.home=C:\WORK\apache-maven-3.2.3 -Dclassworlds.conf=C:\WORK\apache-maven-3.2.3\bin\m2.conf -Didea.launcher.port=7537 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\WORK\apache-maven-3.2.3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.4\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=13.1.4 test -P myProfile
```

Whereas this from same directory on commandline works fine :

```
mvn test -P myProfile
```

The tests that fails are simple dao retrieval integration tests, and the result are incosistent. Ie sometimes it will fail other times not.  It uses google app engine sdk for datastorage

Comment: I was seeing DAO failures inconsistently due to maven surefire using a default forking behaviour to run tests.  Additionally very occassionally failures would occur due to multiple tests being run against the same datasource concurrently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to check that the same jdk is being used when you run mvn from the command line.  Secondly that the same version of mvn is being used on the commandline.

C:\WORK\apache-maven-3.2.3

Once that is confirmed I would run a debug session from within intellij so I can tell which tests fail and why.

Also make sure the permissions available running from within intellj and from the command line are the same.

https://github.com/destin/maven-test-support-plugin

Try installing this to view the test results and work through the failures